# Apply DataTemplate to type derived from FrameworkElement

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, frameworkelement

I've got a list of custom "pages" in my app. Each page represents a different UI view. They have some simple properties, like a string title and an icon, but they also have a number of complex properties, consisting of controls to insert into the main toolbar, a main content area, custom statusbar panels, etc. The page type derives from `FrameworkElement` so that data binding works properly inside of each page's XAML. So far, everything I've described works *great*.

The problem comes when I try to quickly throw up a list of all pages. I've got an `ItemsControl` which I've bound to the list of active pages, and a `DataTemplate` assigned to an `ItemTemplate` consisting of just a label bound to the page's `Title` property (as noted, it's just a plain string). When I run it, however, nothing displays in the list and I get this in the error output:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 25 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are not valid for item.; Type='WelcomePage'

If I change the base type to anything but `FrameworkElement` the template works but data binding within each page breaks down horribly (binding to items via `ElementName` fails, despite both of the involved controls being children of a common `FrameworkElement`, which is defined within the page's XAML).

Anyone know of a way to either get a DataTemplate to apply to a FrameworkElement-derived type or to get data binding to work in a XAML file rooted by a non-FrameworkElement?

Comment: If you are still interested in getting an answer to this could you post your code for the type that derives from FrameworkElement? Framework element has a lot of properties and method with no default implementations and assumes derived classes will provide the correct plumbing. Other classes that derive from FrameworkElement provide implementations which is why things work if you change the class type.

Answer (score 0):

Not that it probably does you any good now, but I had the same issue under similar circumstances. I just substituted the items control for a `listview`. As using a `listbox`  caused me additional binding errors.